# SQL Server outer join issue

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

I'm having a bit of trouble getting an outer join to work: I've had them work as I expected in MS Access in the past, but getting a similar thing happening in SQL Server is giving me issues.

I have a table of scores that apply to each student like:

```
+-------------+------------+-------+
| StudentID   | StandardID | Score |
+-------------+------------+-------+
| 100         | 1011       | 1     |
| 100         | 1012       | 2     |
| 101         | 1011       | 3     |
```

Each student may have many scores, and each score is related to one Standard. Additionally, each student may belong to one or more groups, which are contained within another table, groups:

```
+-------------+------------+
| StudentID   | GroupID    |
+-------------+------------+
| 100         | 83         |
| 101         | 83         |
```

What I want to do is extract the score information and filter it by group: this dataset will then be matched up by StudentID to the correct record elsewhere. However, for each retrieved dataset for any given student, there needs to be exactly the same number of rows: one for each standard. Ideally this (for the above data):

```
StudentID = 100
+------------+-------------+------------+-------+
| StandardID | StudentID   | GroupID    | Score |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------+
| 1011       | 100         | 83         | 1     |
| 1012       | 100         | 83         | 2     |

StudentID = 101
+------------+-------------+------------+-------+
| StandardID | StudentID   | GroupID    | Score |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------+
| 1011       | 101         | 83         | 3     |
| 1012       | 101         | 83         | NULL  | <--Can't get this to happen
```

I can pull up the list that I want but there are not NULL rows in there. As a further example, if I have 4 scores for one student but only 1 score for another, I still need there to be 4 rows returned by the query, with NULLs in for the scores they don't have.

This is what I have tried so far (a bit more verbose, but in essence):

```
SELECT Standards.StandardID, scores.StudentID, scores.TestDate, scores.Score, 
    scores.Assessment
FROM scores RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT scores_1.StandardID
     FROM scores AS scores_1 INNER JOIN studentGroups 
         ON scores_1.StudentID = studentGroups.StudentID
     WHERE (studentGroups.GroupID = 83)
     GROUP BY scores_1.StandardID) AS Standards 
ON scores.StandardID = Standards.StandardID
WHERE scores.StudentID = 100
```

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: how about an `outer join` inside the `subquery` as well. did u try it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us the database structure Because to return same number of rows for all students you need to create a temp table with different StandardIDs and then use outer join to get same number of rows for all students.

provide the table structure for further and appropriate ans.

Answer (score 0):

I use `scores` and `groups` as the two tables described above. You used much more terms so I got (and maybe are) a bit confused. However, this should work:

```
select AllStandards.StandardID,
       groups.StudentID,
       groups.GroupID,
       Scores.Score
from   (select distinct StandardID from scores) AllStandards
       left join (
         scores 
         join groups 
           on groups.StudentID = scores.StudentID
         )
         on AllStandards.StandardID = scores.StandardID
 where groups.StudentID=100
```

I first create a list of all available `StandardID` and then do a left join to all students and scores to get the list.